# How to Run A TypeScript File?

Tags: typescript

As we know, Angular 4+ applications are built with TypeScript.

When we type `ng serve` in the command line for one these apps, the application runs in the browser and responds  to our changes without any `.js` files apparently being created in our project.

Let's say I have a file, `myscript.ts`, that exists outside of an Angular application. How can I create a watch scenario for this so that the file runs in Node, but I don't have to create a new file?

Clearly, the case is not that the file has to be compiled into a `JavaScript` file. We can see when we run `ng serve` that no new files are created.

Comment: you cant, you have to compile it

Comment: you can compiler you file to js and than add reference of it in project

Comment: You have yourself said "apparently" without any .js files created in the project. Well it always does!

Comment: I am not really sure whether I understand you as you are mixing `angular` and `webpack` running in the background during `ng server`, and then `node` running `typescript` on every change, but I guess you are intersted in `ts-node` and/or running typescript with `tsc -w` switch to watch the file changes.

Answer (score 3):

> without any `.js` files apparently being created in our project.

Sometimes the JS only has to exist in memory, so no actual `.js` file is necessarily created on your file system, but the compiler is doing the work to convert `.ts` file to JS at some point, and that is what's served to the browser. The browser only runs JavaScript. However, to make it even more opaque the browser can handle [source maps](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) that will map the running JavaScript back to any original source files (in this case `.ts` files), so in your dev console it really looks like the browser is running TypeScript, but in fact it is running JavaScript that is mapped to original TypeScript source files.

> How can I create a watch scenario for this so that the file runs in Node, but I don't have to create a new file?

You could use [`ts-node`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node). From the docs:

> **TypeScript Node** works by registering the TypeScript compiler for `.tsx?`
>   and `.jsx?` extension (when `allowJs == true`). When node.js has an
>   extension registered (via `require.extensions`), it will use the
>   extension internally for module resolution. When an extension is
>   unknown to node.js, it handles the file as `.js` (JavaScript).